# IntelliJ + Git Bash + Vim: Can't Stop Writing

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm on IntelliJ `2021.3.2` and git `2.35.windows.2`.

A few years ago when typing in my IntelliJ terminal (configured to use Git Bash), when I was done typing out a commit description in vim, I would hit `esc` and then I could execute vim commands.

More recently, hitting `esc` in the IntelliJ terminal now de-focuses (for lack of a better term) the IntelliJ terminal window so it would no longer let me execute vim commands. Then I had to use `ctrl + c` instead of `esc`.

Now with the versions I listed above, I can't even use `ctrl + c`. I still can't use `esc`. So how do I stop writing in vim if I can't use `ctrl + c` or `esc` in order to be able to execute a vim command, namely `:wq`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reassign keybinding for "Switch Focus to Editor" terminal action:

[image: Switch Focus to Editor]